# How to fix Internal Server Error (500) AWS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

this quite weird happen to our server and this happen last week ago and I don't know where this issue came from, The testing procedure that we do is to check in localhost if this module part is working well and check each task if works well. The conclusion of our test is working on the local side. However on our staging and production side some of the api is not working and based on our observation this is on the AWS problem issue.

**First Testing Process** :
What we did right now is to check the Idle timeout of load balancer.

1. From 60 we increase it by 4000 as testing process if this will work but on our testing process still same issue.

[image: Idle Timeout]

**Second Testing Process:**

2. To check again each api if working well and all our api is working well.

Error:

[image: Error Response API]

Comment: Which service you are using to host the application? Can you show the ALB's target group as well?

Comment: I am using elastic beanstalk for the hosting the server. currently we are 4 users using this app but its timeout.

Comment: Beanstalk in which mode? Can you show me the target group of ALB?